# WARNING: Multiple JSF Applications found on same ClassLoader. Unable to safely determine which FactoryManager instance to use

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish, glassfish-3, prettyfaces

I am trying to create an application where I combine jsf2, prettyfaces, jpa and glassfish 3.1. I had some trouble gettings prettyfilter to load properly, which was fixed by following the tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070129/maven-jee6-tomcat-7-glassfish-3-1-ejb-jsf2-hibernate-jpa-and-prettyfaces).

However, after completing the steps I got a problem with the Glassfish log being flooded by some really really irritating warnings mesages. It seams they dont have any impact on the functionality of my page, but I would like to know if there is something that will make them go away? The warning is:

```
WARNING: Multiple JSF Applications found on same ClassLoader.  Unable to safely determine which FactoryManager instance to use. Defaulting to first match
```

In addition I'm having problem undeploying this webapp. Glassfish admin gui will show a text saying "Long lasting process has been detected", before the admin gui is useless and I have to restart the gf server. I get an error in the gf log:

```
INFO: PrettyFilter shutting down...
INFO: Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...
WARNING: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'command' event for 'button1'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'command' event for 'button1'.
```

Not sure if this makes any sense for anyone, but any help is much appreciated!!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both issues are already reported to the Glassfish dev team.

- [Issue GLASSFISH-15809](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15809) - JSF PhaseListener executed for each virtual host
- [Issue GLASSFISH-16112](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16112?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab) - Admin GUI fails with NPE when attempting to undeploy an application

Glassfish 3.2 will be the earliest version where both issues will be fixed.

Comment: aha! stupid me who thought that the released version was stable enough to actually be used...thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can also be seen (sometimes) on GlassFish 4.1, when more than one JSF application is deployed on the server.